# Convert Arabic String to english number in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How to convert non English number to English number like :
"٣٤٨٦٩١٢٨٨١" to "3486912881" in Swift
or I want to accept just english numbers and obtain others.

In Java Android this code is working for me:

```
private static String arabicToDecimal(String number) {
    char[] chars = new char[number.length()];
    for(int i=0;i<number.length();i++) {
        char ch = number.charAt(i);
        if (ch >= 0x0660 && ch <= 0x0669)
           ch -= 0x0660 - '0';
        else if (ch >= 0x06f0 && ch <= 0x06F9)
           ch -= 0x06f0 - '0';
        chars[i] = ch;
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

do like

```
     let NumberStr: String = "٢٠١٨-٠٦-٠٤"
    let Formatter = NumberFormatter()
    Formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "EN") as Locale!
    if let final = Formatter.number(from: NumberStr) {
        print(final)

    }
```

**output**

[image]

the alternate way

**Option 2**

```
extension String {
    public var arToEnDigits : String {
        let arabicNumbers = ["٠": "0","١": "1","٢": "2","٣": "3","٤": "4","٥": "5","٦": "6","٧": "7","٨": "8","٩": "9"]
        var txt = self
        arabicNumbers.map { txt = txt.replacingOccurrences(of: $0, with: $1)}
        return txt
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of the `final != 0` check, you could simply use optional binding; `if let final = Formatter.numberFromString(NumberStr) { print(final) }`. Also, variable names such as `NumberStr` and `Formatter` above should (by convention) be named with initial small letter as `camelCase`, not as `CamelCase` (which is reserved for e.g. _types_).

Comment: Thank u so much bro.

Comment: good solution but if the number begin with 0 it will be removed and it will cause a problem in mobile numbers

Comment: This won't work in case the string begis with zero like "0055" it will then be converted to "55". 
How can I solve this??

Comment: It will remove zero('s) from begining of string-number.

Comment: My number is like this ٢٠١٨ 432432 
How to possible mix language number convert into english number?

Comment: option 1 doesn't support + in it. it must be replaced before convert

Answer (score 19):

The problem with using `NumberFormatter` is that it will ignore other non numeric characters, for example if you have `Hello ١٢٣` it will be `123`. To keep other characters and only convert numeric ones, you can use the following:

```
public extension String {

public var replacedArabicDigitsWithEnglish: String {
    var str = self
    let map = ["٠": "0",
               "١": "1",
               "٢": "2",
               "٣": "3",
               "٤": "4",
               "٥": "5",
               "٦": "6",
               "٧": "7",
               "٨": "8",
               "٩": "9"]
    map.forEach { str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: $0, with: $1) }
    return str
}
}

/// usage

"Hello ١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩١٠".replacedArabicDigitsWithEnglish // "Hello 12345678910"
```

Comment: I used your codes But I received this warning 
Expression of type 'String' is unused

Comment: I think it will be better to make it a function, not a computed var, computed var should be used if it returns a value that represents an attribute, but this is a function :)

Comment: is there no way to generalize this so that it works for every language without having a huge map of characters?

Comment: What other languages that use different numbers other than English?

Answer (score 5):

**To use above codes as function try this:**

```
func toEnglishNumber(number: String) -> NSNumber {

       var result:NSNumber = 0

    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "EN")
    if let finalText = numberFormatter.number(from: number)
    {
        print("Intial text is: ", number)
        print("Final text is: ", finalText)


        result =  finalText

    }


     return result
}
```

**To use the function:**

```
 print(toEnglishNumber(number: "١٢"))
```

Comment: this code here has problem when first number is 0 But the above code will replace the numbers to English not convert them But the only problem is how to use that

Comment: It will remove zero('s) from begining of string-number.

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 3.0 Or up:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "EN")
    if let finalText = numberFormatter.number(from: "text here")
    {
      print("Final text is: ", finalText)
    }
```

Comment: good solution but if the number begin with 0 it will be removed 
and it will cause a problem in mobile numbers

Comment: @AhmadLabeeb found a solution for your problem??

Comment: @EnasAZ yes i think hossam gareeb's solution is perfect
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48135109/5212377

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest and `Swifty` way is using `compactMap`:

```
//this code is for Persian numbers, but you can easily change number dictionary values to arabic numbers.

    extension String {

        func convertToPersianNum() -> String {
            let numbers:[Character : Character] = ["1":"۱","2":"۲","3":"۳","4":"۴","5":"۵","6":"۶","7":"۷","8":"۸","9":"۹","0":"۰"]

            let converted = String(self.compactMap{numbers[$0]})

            return converted

        }

    }


    "123456".convertToPersianNum() //۱۲۳۴۵۶
```