# Hindi numeric set Integer value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any pure swift way to transform hindi/other language integers to Int without using help of NSString
Following are my observations:

```
let string = "४"
let intParse1 = Int(string) //goes for nil, why? is there any pure solution in swift
let intParse2 = (string as NSString).integerValue //goes for 4
```

Comment: [Basically same problem, different locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923969/convert-arabic-string-to-english-number-in-swift).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `NumberFormatter`

```
    let numberFormat= NumberFormatter()
    numberFormat.locale = Locale(identifier: "EN")
    if let getOP = numberFormat.number(from: "४")
    {
        print("output is: ", getOP)
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I want to know one more thing about this if I want to translate this number to any other language so like I input "४" and want the output in Arabic?  And If I removed this line : numberFormat.locale = Locale(identifier: "EN") so still it is working

Comment: @iOSTeam - in here I added my answer as static, if you need to convert from one language to any language, you need to change locale for e.g if you want to change the english to Arabic use **Locale(identifier: "ar")**