# Convert one Hindi language number to Arabic language number

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

I have come across one question
[Hindi numeric set Integer value in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54708382/hindi-numeric-set-integer-value-in-swift)

It was about how we can convert Hindi to English any number value.

Curious about to know how we can convert one language number to another language number

Like Example: trying to convert Hindi Language number to the Arabic language

Here is the code I have tried in the playground :

```
let string = "४"

let intParse1 = Int(string)

let numberFormat = NumberFormatter()
numberFormat.locale = Locale(identifier: "ar")

if let getOP = numberFormat.number(from: string) {
    print("output is: ", getOP)
}
```

Here is the output it is showing in the English only

[image]

I have searched for this problem but not found this kind of specific solution so posting a new question for it.

Note: Not looking for any static conversion extension or that kind of function.

**EDIT:**
I don't want this kind of solution

[convert arabic String to english number in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923969/convert-arabic-string-to-english-number-in-swift/48135109#48135109)

**EDIT 2:**

I want to know about why we have to convert to it first to a number and then convert it to Arabic?, Means it is necessary to convert it first to English?

Comment: Do you mean something other than the [Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals) `0...9`? Could you clarify your question by editing it and specifying the desired result?

Comment: @Carpsen90 I have edited the question.

Comment: This question causes a little confusion because in English, the digits commonly used in English (0..9) are always called "Arabic" and the digits commonly used in Arabic (٠..٩) are sometimes called "Hindi."

Comment: I want to convert simply my Hindi number value to Arabic or any other Language like Turkish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Explanation :**
`NumberFormatter` converts the number into another language number, not a string of a language to other language. So first we have to convert one language number number and then to another language number.

**Doc Explanation :** [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter)

> Instances of NumberFormatter format the textual representation of cells that contain NSNumber objects and convert textual representations of numeric values into NSNumber objects. The representation encompasses integers, floats, and doubles; floats and doubles can be formatted to a specified decimal position. NumberFormatter objects can also impose ranges on the numeric values cells can accept.

Directly use this extension for **Swift 4**:

```
extension String {
    func convertToArbic () -> String? {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "hi")
        guard let number = formatter.number(from:self ) else{
            return nil
        }
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ar")
        guard let number2 = formatter.string(from: number) else{
            return nil
        }
        return number2
    }
}

// use
let string = "४"
if let arbNumber = string.convertToArbic() {
    print(arbNumber)
}
else{
    print("Unable to get arabic number")
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Suggestion: You should return optional string and return nil. in case of fail

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Doing same wait

Comment: I want to know about why we have to convert to it first to a number and then convert it to Arabic?, Means it is necessary to convert it first to English? 
Because if I print ("number  \(number)") so it will give me 4

Comment: @iOSTeam Check expalantion.

Comment: @iOSTeam Same thing  we   are doing  with  `Dateformatter`

Comment: I think question also need ^ :)

Answer (score 2):

Try Following code :

```
let Formatter = NumberFormatter()
Formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "EN")
if let hindiNumber = Formatter.number(from: "४") {
    Formatter.locale =  Locale(identifier: "ar")
    let formattedNumber = Formatter.string(from: hindiNumber)
    print(formattedNumber!)
}
```

Comment: Check with integer value as an input parameter.

Comment: I want Hindi to Arabic, not number to Arabic Number

Comment: @iOSTeam I think it's just because of some base number system. i.e English in iOS. even your project language is English.

Comment: I think question also need (Y)

Answer (score 1):

A more generic solution, which lets you convert from and to any locale

```
extension NSNumber {
    static func from(value: String, localeIdentifier: String) -> NSNumber? {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: localeIdentifier)

        return numberFormatter.number(from: value)
    }

    func to(localeIdentifier: String) -> String {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: localeIdentifier)

        return numberFormatter.string(from: self) ?? "<undefined>"
    }
}

print("४ is the number \(NSNumber.from(value: "४", localeIdentifier: "hi")!)")
print("5 is \(NSNumber(value: 5).to(localeIdentifier: "ar")) in arabic")
```

The output will be:

```
४ is the number 4
5 is ٥ in arabic
```

**ANSWER TO EDIT 2:**

Numeric string values are nothing but a representation of the numeric value. `NumberFormatter` always uses the numeric value as the point of truth and uses it to be able to transform to a different locale. That's why you MUST convert to the numeric value first if you use this class.

However, you can write your own function that has no knowledge of the numeric value and just maps between strings to convert the numeric values, for example:

```
var hindiToArabicMap: [String: String] = ["४": "٥"]
print("४ in arabic is \(hindiToArabicMap["४"]!)")
```

The output will be:

```
४ in arabic is ٥
```

Comment: @Deniel Great !!! Explanation, Thanks for making it very clear and understandable.